# How to get just the image format with Magick/py-wand?

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I'm using [py-wand](http://docs.wand-py.org) to read images in Python. All I really want though is the image meta information, like size, format, color depth, etc. I don't want to load the entire image. Some of my images are extremely large and loading them this way is causing memory problems.

How can I get just the meta information?

Answer (score 0):

The Magickwand method for this is [MagickPingImageFile](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickPingImageFile).  I quickly skimmed the pywand documentation and didn't see a binding to this method, but it might be provided under another name than 'ping'.  It may require a feature request.